# Retracting flags

Tags: support, editing, flagging

Initially I wanted to flag a question because of certain reasons.  However, after the OP edited, I do not want to flag anymore.  1. Would my flag be declined? 2. Should I retract my flag?

Comment: As general advice, don't fret over a declined flag. If it's a pattern where multiple flags of the same type get rejected, then you do need to readjust some thresholds there, but if it's a single flag the consequences are between minimal and null and you should just let it go.

Answer (score 2):

1. If the edit fixed the issue, yes. The flag will probably be rejected.
2. If you think the edit fixed the issue, yes. You should retract your flag.

If the edit did not really fix the issue, you should not retract the flag, and should not expect it to be rejected.

Comment: I guess the user did edit slightly, but my flag got accepted anyways